# Calculate tf-idf weight for only given word list with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to get tf-idf weights for given word list from the documents.
for example, I have the words interested in like below.

```
document_list = ['''document 1 blabla''', '''document 2 blabla''']
words = ['project', 'management', 'uml theory', 'wireframe']
```

Of course I can get terms and weights from documents using sklearn.
but I want to get only the weight of above words from the document group using scikit-learn.
Any idea will help me a lot.

Comment: Do you want to treat the whole list as a single document?

Comment: multiple documents but I don't want to get terms extracted by scikit-learn.
I need tf-idf weight for my words.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: you know, we can get lsa terms from the scikit-learn with weight.
but I don't want the auto extracted lsa terms from the scikit-learn.
I want the tf-idf weight for my word list using scikit-learn.

Comment: I don't believe that `TfIdfVectorizer` uses LSA so I am still confused.

Comment: that's not important. what I want is to get tf-idf weight for above word list from my documents sir

Comment: OK, well, as best as I understand you so far, scikit-learn might  not actually be the appropriate tool for the job. However, here is some code that might help you: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-process-textual-data-using-tf-idf-in-python-cd2bbc0a94a3

Comment: yes. I already checked it but it's good if I can get the tf-idf weight from scikit-learn. 
Because I'm already using it in some other part of my project.

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm fairly sure `TfIdfVectorizer` isn't tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as easy as fitting `TfidfVectorizer` to your fixed list of desired words and then using your model.

Proof:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
words = ['project', 'management', 'uml theory', 'wireframe']
mod_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
mod_tfidf.fit_transform(words)
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Add one word more and see that number of second dimensions is still `5`:

```
mod_tfidf.transform(words + ["dummy"])
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

**Edit**:

given your updated question and comment:

```
mod_tfidf.fit(words)
mod_tfidf.transform(document_list)
```

**Edit2**:

For the sake of completeness, initializing `TfidfVectorizer` with `vocabulary` param also delivers the same results. Pay attention in this case `words` is list of separate single words:

```
mod_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=words)
```

In this case ordering of the resulting features will be fixed by your `words` order. You may check it by:

```
mod_tfidf.get_feature_names()
```

Comment: I've updated the question so that you understand better.
I think mod_tfidf.fit_transform(document_list).
here we need to use document_list not my words.

Comment: I have documents and I have interesting words, I need to get tf-idf weight for my words with documents.

Comment: I have nothing to add given your edit. Use your words to `fir()` model and then `transform()` the iterable of desired docs, not `fit_transform` as in your comment.

Comment: I cannot see where did you use document_list in your code?

Comment: Cool. I'll test this and will let you know.

Comment: so first mod_tfidf.fit_transform(words) and then mod_tfidf.transform(document_list)   ?
where can I get result after doing this two command?
sorry for my stupid question

Comment: First `fit()` is a dummy command that will fix vocabulary. The result of the second `transform() `is the desired transformation either in sparse form or dense if you do `transform(docs).todense()`. The shape is (n_docs, fixed_vocab). The columns will correspond to the ordered list of your words

Comment: fit_transform is not necessary? fit(words) and then transform(docs).todense() ?

Comment: Right! `fit_transform()` was for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I tried it but when I try with ['project', 'management', 'uml theory', 'wireframe'] and ['management', 'project', 'uml theory', 'wireframe']
I'm getting same value.
I switched the order of the words in the list, but result array value is same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188389/discussion-between-kyl-and-sergey-bushmanov).